# Google Play, Это приложение доступно для 0 и более устройств

Tags: android, google-play

Во время публикации приложения в Google Play в анкете присутствует пункт "Поддерживаемые устройства". В справке сказано, что там должны быть указан список моделей телефонов, на которых будет работать приложение. Но в моем случае там написано следующее:

> В соответствии с манифестом ваше приложение доступно только для устройств с этими функциями.
>   Это приложение доступно для 0 и более устройств.

Что это значит? Мое приложение доступно для всех телефонов? Мое приложение не будет работать ни на одном телефоне? Или что?

Comment: Манифест можете показать?

Answer (score 4):

Вопрос на самом деле при всей кажущейся простоте довольно сложный. Попробую ответить по порядку:

1. Нужен ваш манифест, в манифесте есть по крайней мере с десяток параметров активно влияющих на совместимость с устройствами. Самые простые это типа `minSdkVersion`. Есть еще `<uses-feature>`, `<supports-screen>` и проч.
2. Играет роль на какой версии SDK было скомпилировано приложение. По идее надо компилировать на максимально высокой версии, но опять же не всегда - иногда возникает проблема с поддержкой очень старых версий API. Моя личная рекомендация (*по состоянию на 2012 год*) использовать API 10.
3. Маркет - чрезвычайно глючная штука. Он запросто на ровном месте может показывать, что поддерживаемых аппаратов "ноль" и одновременно если попросить какие конкретно модели поддерживаются покажет немалый список. Лечится это сохранением/апдейтом.

Answer (score 1):

Похоже на то, что вы не так указали целевой level API.

Проверьте свои значения для

`android:minSdkVersion, android:targetSdkVersion, android:maxSdkVersion`.

Answer (score 1):

Тоже самое было когда публиковал приложение в маркет. В итоге получилось так, что приложение доступно для всех устройств. Это факт из практики недельной давности.
Могу предположить, что это произошло из-за того, что у меня в приложении использовался sdk 13, но minSDK было версии 7 (android 2.1), т.е. приложение должно было устанавливаться на все устройства с sdk 7 и выше, что в итоге и получилось.
Так что можете не обращать внимание на данный пункт. :)

Answer (score 0):

Может быть вы просто не активировали ваш апк? Во вкладке файлы апк, надо нажать активировать и в списке устройств появляются устройства

Answer (score -1):

Это из-за того, что у тебя слишком много uses-permission в манифесте. Например, если ты используешь акселерометр, то приложение не установится на большинстве телефонов. Так же плохо сказываются компасы и всякого рода датчики, не имеющего общего с GEO location. 
В общем, удали (например) все пермишены - и увидишь, что уже очень много телефонов доступно!